# Internal server error 500 on codeigniter Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using ajax to retreive data from the database and am receiving a weird internal server error 500 on this query and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. The issue is with `->get()->result()`, when I remove that I am not getting a internal server error as response. The whole query:

```
$this->db->select('bikes.store_id')->from('mappings')->where('mappings.product_id', $prod_id)->join('bikes', 'bikes.product_id = mappings.product_id')->get()->result()
```

Comment: Try `print_r($result)` of your query is there any error..

Comment: How can I print_r the result when it's giving an internal server error on the query. I tried wrapping print_r around it but still getting internal server error.

Comment: Try `print_r($result);exit;` and check what you are getting over there

Comment: I don't even have a variable $result? And if you mean the variable that I store the result in, that won't work because an internal 500 error is being given at the moment when it is executing the get->result functions so it will not show anything. @NarendraSisodia

Comment: Then place code like `Eko Junaidi Salam` and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your joining query is incorrect.

```
$this->db->select('bikes.store_id')->from('mappings')->join('bikes', 'bikes.product_id = mappings.product_id')->where('mappings.product_id', $prod_id)->get()->result();
```

Try out this query.

Write below in your controller to see what query is being generated.

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Comment: The codeigniter db class will put it in the right order, but I tried your answer as well, yet no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you are having matching records as per query as you only can fetch result if you find any record in the DB otherwise it will return bool(false) in response.

Comment: I still wouldn't get a internal server error, I am storing the response in a variable and it gives me an internal server error when executing the query itself.

Comment: Try to give alias of tables rather than using table full name like bikes.store_id. Try bikes as b and fetch like b.store_id

Comment: I hope you have followed structure like ajax - TO- Controller- TO - module. And module contains your query.

Comment: View --> Controller --> Model to handle SQL. Offcourse I have done it the right way :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74708/discussion-between-pari-and-jordy).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you misplaces something :

```
$this->db->select('bikes.store_id')->from('mappings')->join('bikes', 'bikes.product_id = mappings.product_id','left')->where('mappings.product_id', $prod_id);
$result = $this->db->get()->result();
```

You can get the data using $result indeed.

Comment: Also tried that as well, tried it again and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('bikes.store_id');
$this->db->from('mappings');
$this->db->join('bikes', 'bikes.product_id = mappings.product_id','left');
$this->db->where('mappings.product_id', $prod_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

try this out.If it does not work try echo **$this->db->last_query();** to get the last SQL query.Get back with the error.Hope it solves your problem